# Inner Tube Replacement

Tags: tire

I have a Schwinn Volare 1200 Youth Road Bike that need Inner Tube replacement...However, the 26 x 1.0 measurement of its tire is so hard to find. So, Is there any other measurements that can be used as replacements?

Thanks

Comment: Unlike tires themselves, inner tubes can be pretty flexible. What's the closest width you've been able to find?

Comment: You may well be able to find 26x1.25--1.5 which would work. The exact size should be easy to find online so you can get a spare or two.

Comment: Amazon had the correct size (26x1-1.25) when I searched.  Your LBS should have them or be able to order them.  If they can't, don't go back there (ever) and order them online.

Comment: They have this tube size at Walmart, even. But most bike shops will probably have it.

Comment: Note that bike tubes are "sized" for a range of widths, typically spanning 25-35% of the narrowest value.  And one can, with only modest risk to durability use a tube that is a little "too narrow" or "too wide", based on the size range on the box.

Comment: In a pinch length is more important than width.  So pretty much any smaller 650 or 26" tube should work.  Tubes inflate to fill the space available, so a 1.5-1.75" tube will simply not expand as much.  It runs the risk of a fold or a pinch in the tube, and conversely decreases your puncture risk by being not quite as taut when inflated.  You do want to get the right valve though.

Answer (score 1):

650c x 25 or so should work fine as a replacement for that if all else fails...  This is because they are the same ISO Diameter.  That's an International Standard for measuring tires that takes the diameter of the bead as the measurement, since that's the primary interface from wheel to tire.  Most tires are labeled by their inflated diameter, + or - some cheating on sizes, deep tread patterns and just generally not having good standards in the industry among different countries making them.  ISO takes none of that into account and simply measures where the tire meets the rim.

Both 26x1 and 650c are 571mm ISO.  The second number in any of the Metric tires is simply the width.  Your 26x1 is about 25mm wide, so you should look for a 650cx25 tube, or thereabouts.

One more thing, I say that size or thereabouts because tubes are rubber.  They stretch.  It usually isn't a problem if they are just a little big or a little small.  Given the choice, err on the side of them being a little big.  So even if the closest you can find is 26x1.25 or 650cX28, that should work fine too.